# Get multiple data from multiple tables in MYSQL by using single query

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an application
My question is how can we get multiple data from multiple tables in MYSQL by using single query...? I'm using XAMPP. how can i use join statement? for an example i am attaching snapshots of my tables ...[image: table of education]

[image: table of requirements]

Now all i want to get the degree from education and qualification from requirement. 
NOTE: my tables are still empty i just need a help with query.

Comment: what relates the two tables? is qualification related to degree?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html "JOIN Syntax") and following the examples (including those in the User Comments section)?

Comment: @AndriyM Shh, don't mention the manual. It's supposed to be secret!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go in the SQL tab and type the join yourself but I do not see a link between those two tables. You need to link them together first then run something like this:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2 FROM TABLE1 t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.TABLE1ID
```

Comment: How can i relate them Micallef. ? I have already done this through designer option. is there is some mistake i've done in my database. ?

Comment: How are they related? Is it fair to say that 1 education can only have 1 requirement?  If yes, then you can place a ReqrID (or any name you want) in the education table. In this ReqrID, you will be inserting IDs from the other table.  So when you are creating a record in the education table, you need to select a value from the requirements table and associate it with it. I suggest these are linked through a Relation as well (click Relation View in the Structure page)